# How to solve $x^2 \equiv 12 \pmod {13}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Solve $x^2 \equiv 12 \pmod {13}$

By guessing I can say that the solutions are $5$ and $8$, but is there another way to find the solution besides guessing?

Comment: You can use [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), but with such small numbers trial and error is probably 
 faster.

Comment: We didn't have Wilsons Theorem yet, so I guess it's either guessing or something other, maybe something with the CRT?

Comment: I don't see how the CRT is relevant.  Trial and error is a perfectly sensible method.  Like I say, with small numbers I think it is preferable to more algebraic means.

Comment: Convert $12$ to some perfect square: $x^2 \equiv 25 \pmod {13}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm

Comment: Note:  if $x\equiv5$ is a solution, then so is $x\equiv-5\equiv8$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As cosmo5 mentioned in his comment. You can do the following which is a little bit better than guessing since you probably can instantly recognise square numbers.
For every natural number $n$ we have
$$
x^2 \equiv 12 \mod 13 
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
x^2 \equiv 12+13n \mod 13.
$$
Hence, you can start
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
n & 12+13n \\
\hline
1 & 25 \\
2 & 38 \\
3 & 51 \\
4 & 64
\end{array}
$$
Then you will see that for $n=1$ you have $5^2$ and for $n=4$ you have $8^2$, which gives you the solutions $x_1=5$ and $x_2=8$.

Alternative you can make a polynomial division after you found one solution, because
$$
x^2-12 \equiv (x-x_1)(x-x_2) \mod 13.
$$
However, this might take longer than guessing for small numbers.

Comment: once you found $x_1$ then automatically $x_2=-x_1=13-x_1$, we don't really need polynomial division.

Comment: @zwim good point.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint :**

As $x^2 \equiv a^2 \pmod {n}$ is easiest to handle, and $12\equiv25 \pmod {13}$, we have

$$ x^2 \equiv (\pm 5)^2 \pmod {13}$$

Comment: Extending @cosmo5's answer, we may also solve $x^2 \equiv 64 \mod 13$

Answer (score 0):

In the special case of trying to find a square root of $-1$ modulo a prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, we can use the following algorithm: first, select some random integer $a$ with $1 < a < p - 1$.  Now, if $p-1 = 2^k \cdot q$ with $q$ odd, then form $a^q \operatorname{mod} p$.  If you get something other than $1$ or $-1$ at this point, then repeatedly square until you get $-1$.  Then, the number just before $-1$ will be a square root of $-1$.  (The reason this works: by Fermat's little theorem, $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, so after taking the square $k$ times, you get to $1$.  Since $p$ is prime, the number just before you reach $1$ for the first time is forced to be $-1$.)

On the other hand, if $a^q \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}$ already, then go back and choose another random value of $a$ to try.  Since $q < \frac{p - 1}{2}$, it is impossible for every value of $a$ to satisfy $a^q \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p} \Leftrightarrow a^{2q} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

So, in the case of $p = 13$, where $p - 1 = 2^2 \cdot 3$ and so $q = 3$, let us first start with a trial of $a = 2$.  Then, $a^q = 2^3 = 8$ and $8 \not\equiv \pm 1 \pmod{13}$, so we're good to go.  From here, $8^2 = 64 \equiv -1 \pmod{13}$, and so we find 8 as a square root of $-1 \pmod{13}$.

Answer (score 0):

In the field ${\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} /13\mathbb {Z}}$, $\,[1] + [1] \ne [0]$, and therefore there are either zero or two distinct $\text{modulo-}13$ solutions for,

$\tag 1 x^2 \equiv 12 \pmod{13}$

When one solution $[u]$ has been found the other solution is $-[u]$.

We have

$\; \large x^2 \equiv 12 \pmod{13} \; \text{ iff }$
$\; \large x^2 \equiv 2^{-2} \cdot (2^2 \cdot 12) \pmod{13} \; \text{ iff }$
$\; \large x^2 \equiv 2^{-2} \cdot (3^2) \pmod{13} \; \text{ iff }$
$\; \large x^2 \equiv \bigr(2^{-1} \cdot 3^1\bigr)^2 \pmod{13}$

Now the inverse of $[2]$ is easily calculated,

$\quad [2]^{-1} = [\frac{13 + 1}{2}] = [7]$

and so one solution to $\text{(1)}$ is given by

$\quad x \equiv 7 \cdot 3 \equiv 8 \pmod{13}$

The other solution is given by

$\quad x \equiv -8 \equiv 5 \pmod{13}$

---

Note: Examining this question resulted in a [conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3901694/432081),

$\quad$ A new method for finding a solution (when they exist) to $x^2 = a \pmod p$?